# Is there any free BDC generator?

Tags: sharepoint, bdc

I'm looking for BDC generator, I found great one: [MOSS BDC Design Studio](http://www.simego.com/products/MOSS-BDC-Design-Studio) but is there any free BDC generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a free tool available from Microsoft for creating BDC Application Definitions. Get it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100701172815/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sharepoint/archive/2007/08/22/announcing-the-microsoft-business-data-catalog-definition-editor-for-microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007.aspx)

If memory serves it doesn´t create a `full` application definition, I think it doesn´t create a Enumerator MethodInstance for your data. This means that if you want to use the Business Data List webpart you´ll still have to do some coding. But at least it´ll give you a place to start...